# How to pass a variable to a filter

Tags: flask, jinja2

In a flask application context, I try to process some text using jinja2 custom filters:

for example:

```
 <td>{{ data.get('value')  | convert(data.get('unit'), 'psi') }}</td>
```

works perfectly, with `convert()` being my custom filter.

However, when I try to pass a user setting (from flask app: `current_user.pref_display_unit`):

```
<td>{{ data.get('value')  | convert(data.get('unit'), {{ current_user.pref_display_unit }}) }}</td>
```

fails with:

```
File "N:\05-dev\flask_dev\carnac\carnac\templates\honeycomb\index.html", line 42, in template
    <td>{{ data.get('long beam_L')  | convert(data.get('unit'), {{  current_user.pref_display_thousandsep }}) }}</td>
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

So, how to pass such a varable to a filter?

Comment: If the `current_user` is in your jinji's context, you can use it dierectly, need no "{{  }}", just `convert(data.get('unit'), current_user.pref_display_unit) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the noise: this one was easy. Just pass the variable itself without brackets:

```
<td>{{ data.get('value')  | convert(data.get('unit'), current_user.pref_display_unit) }}</td>
```